# Good Sites for GPU Reference?

Tags: discussion, meta

Just like my question about CPU specifications - what does this community think would make a useful reference for retrieving GPU specifications quickly and easily? Of course you can go to manufacturer websites to slowly and laboriously retrieve data, but in my experience manufacturers don't always provide all the needed information, at least in one spot, and sometimes they are just hard to find in general (think mobile GPUs).

Once again, my expertise in the x86 space shows its weakness when it comes to mobile; I don't have anything to suggest for the Mali, Videocore, or other mobile GPUs series.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Wikipedia, I like the [Tom's Hardware GPU hierarchy](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gpu-hierarchy,4388.html).  No, it doesn't have raw numbers, but it does give a good idea of how various cards rank in real-world performance.

Comment: Very, very cool, but not  spec sheet comparison or lookup tool, which is what we are looking for here..

Answer (score 1):

For GPUs in the x86 desktop and laptop space, I have the following resources:

- [Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units)
- [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_RX_M400_Series)
- [Nvidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units)

But conspicuously missing is any listing of AMD's APU graphics lineup. I have yet to find a good resource on these. You can make *rough* comparisons to mobile and discrete chips with similar specifications, but benchmarks show that they do tend to behave differently.